PythonKit integration with Swift - Crashing on release due to module import
I have a project that is using Swift (for interface) and Python (for function) for a Mac application.
I added PythonKit as a dependency and after:

removing "App Sandbox" from "Signing & Capabilities"
turning "Enable Hardened Runtime" off
Setting environment variable "PYTHON_LIBRARY" to "/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11"

Now everything works as hoped and when I run it works great.
However, now I archive the Xcode project -> Distribute -> Custom -> Copy App. It creates an instance of the application to where I save it and as soon as I open it it opens for a few milliseconds (the window never opens) and it immediately crashes with this warning window:
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]

OS Version:            macOS 14.0 (23A344)
Report Version:        12

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000019f534658

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [97502]

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib          0x19f534658 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 268
1   libswiftCore.dylib          0x19f5a0cf8 swift_unexpectedError + 516
2   Filex                       0x102576428 PythonInterface.import(_:) + 148 (Python.swift:707)
3   Filex                       0x10256f7e8 PythonAPI.init() + 568 (PythonAPI.swift:24)
4   Filex                       0x10256f5a4 PythonAPI.__allocating_init() + 44
5   Filex                       0x102541a30 implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in variable initialization expression of Main._pythonAPI + 28
6   SwiftUI                     0x1bb15ab5c 0x1ba412000 + 13929308

Notes: It looks like it's crashing at this function:
public init() {        
   // Initialize Python
   system = Python.import("sys")
   system.path.append("/Users/reidhtaylor/Documents/Projects/Python/Filex/FilexBackend")
        
   // Get main file
   main = Python.import("main") //!!!! AT THIS LINE #24 !!!!//
}

First of all I don't understand why it works fine when I "Run" the project but "Archive doesn't work". Also I don't get how system.path.append should work cause won't everyones path be different when I build the app? And yes the main.py file is in the FilexBackend folder and it works when Running the project.
I tried settings "Strip Style" to only "Debugging Symbols" (didn't work) and I couldn't find the settings "Enable Bitcode" to try turning it off (which is a fix I saw online)

Even if you have removed Sandbox it still looks suspicious that you use such a personal and hardcoded path as “/Users/reidhtaylor/…” in your app. No one else will have that path on their computer. You can still have the library in the documents folder but you should use the tools available to get the path to the current users document folder. I have no idea if this is relevant to the crash but it’s a better way to work with local paths
